# How can I hide a line of java code from SCA sourceanalyzer?

Tags: java, security, fortify

I have a project that is showing false positives in sourceanalyzer reports. For example, using a static variable named PASSWORD_DIALOG_TAG is reported as a hard coded password even though it's not. I'd like to be able to hide this line or suppress this particular warning in my fortify reports. Note, I don't want to suppress all warnings for hardcoded passwords, just this one.

I know that for this particular warning I could simply change the variable name, but there are other types of warnings that aren't as easily rectified.

Comment: Can't you add PASSWORD_DIALOG_TAG to a "safe" list like in other SAST tools?

Comment: yaloner: Maybe? Where would I find the safe list? I'm using the command line if that changes anything.

Comment: You could try to import fortify's annotation library and the annotate the field as `@FortifyNotPassword`.

Comment: Thanks. If I have any other false positives I'll give that library a shot. I eventually just changed all variable names that were like that. Apparently "paswod" gets past the scanners. :-|

Comment: @Robert: This is interesting concept. Can you provide some sample code to show how this one works? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

I would first confirm it is really a false positive by AWB >> Group By [Category Analyzer]. If the PASSWORD... is found by the Semantic analyzer, then it is high possibility that the issue is due to keyword "PASS/PASSWD/PASSWORD/SSN/TXTNO..." etc.

There are 4 ways to hide an issue.

**(1) @AWB suppress it:** This is not recommended as it would suppress all current and FUTURE issue under this RULEGUID. However, the issue can be found in the DB and can be reverted.
[image: AWB center lower pane, summary tab]

**(2) @AWB NAI it: ** This is recommended. Click on the Analysis tag and mark it Not an Issue (see above picture)

**(3) @AWB Filter it:** Top menu bar >>Options >>Show View >>Filter >>Visibility Filter >> Create New filter >> a pop up wizard shows up >> Category contains .
This method is compliment to other methods. After you suppressing/NAIing and issue, you can make the false positive disappear from your list.

**(4) exclude certain file from being scanned** by command line parameter -exclude /absolute path of dir/file.name (list here for reference only...)

Comment: I'm using just the command line. Is there a different way to do this?